# font family not found in Windows font database

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

when I use rstudio in win11, I cannot use custom fonts for ggplot, I look previous question about this in Stack Overflow but none of them help me.
I run a simple code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Noto Mono"))
```

and these warnings shown in Console:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
3: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
4: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
5: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
6: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
7: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
8: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
9: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
10: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
11: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
12: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
13: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
14: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
15: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
16: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
```

How to fix this?
I want to use [Vazirmatn](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazirmatn) for adding some Persian text as label, title & etc. I installed Vazirmatn & Noto Mono in my device, none of my installed font works with `element_text(family = "my_font_family")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use extrafont library?
You can change the font of ggplot function in R by using extrafont package1. Here are the steps:

Install extrafont package using this command:
`install.packages("extrafont")`
Load extrafont package:
`library(extrafont)`
Import Vazirmatn font:
`font_import(pattern = "Vazirmatn")`
Register Vazirmatn font:
`loadfonts(device = "win")`
Use Vazirmatn font in ggplot function:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
    theme(text=element_text(family="Vazirmatn"))
```

Comment: @user21455910 thanks, it's working surprisingly, One of the previous question mentioned this, but did not work for me, I think it's a bug